# Kotlin class instance assert not correct

Tags: kotlin

I'm converting a Java project into Kotlin.  I've converted a `User` object into Kotlin and when I run the existing JUnit tests in Java I'm getting a error between two instances of the Kotlin `User` object.

**User.kt:**

```
data class User (
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
var id: Long? = null,
...
)
```

**TestUtil.java**

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

public class TestUtil {
    public static void equalsVerifier(Class clazz) throws Exception {
        Object domainObject1 = clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();
        // Test with an instance of the same class
        Object domainObject2 = clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();
        assertThat(domainObject1).isNotEqualTo(domainObject2);
    }
}
```

The `assertThat(domainObject1).isNotEqualTo(domainObject2)` test fails, as I believe in Java comparison is not done correctly on the Kotlin class.  If I run this through a debugger, I can see that `domainObject1` and `domainObject2` are different instances.

Is it possible to get this test case to pass?  The same test case is used for other Java classes, so it has to work for both Java and Kotlin classes.

Comment: IF you remove the `data` keywords the failed test will be pass, this is because Kotlin [data class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html#data-classes) will generates `equals` method to comparing with properties in primary constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `isNotEqualTo` calls `equals`. The Kotlin class implements correct `equals` method for `data class`. So `domainObject1.equals(domainObject2)` is true. This behavior is correct.

just look at the AssertJ document:

```
isNotSameAs(Object other): 
   Verifies that the actual value is not the same as the given one, 
   ie using == comparison.
```

I think you should try:

```
    assertThat(domainObject1).isNotSameAs(domainObject2);
```

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin, `equals()` is generated automatically for `data class` to check for equality of the properties.

Quote from "Kotlin in Action":

> The generated equals() method checks that the values of all the properties are equal. ... Note that properties that aren’t declared in the primary constructor don’t take part in the equality checks and hashcode calculation.

If you want to pass the test case without modifying it, you may override `equals()` of your data class to check for [referential equality](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/equality.html#referential-equality).

```
override fun equals(other: Any?) = this === other
```

Note that it may affect your other code, if there is any function which relies on [structural equality](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/equality.html#structural-equality) of your data class. So, I suggest that you refer to @shawn's answer to change your test case instead.